# Counting the number of same elements in a sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

(Cross-posted to Math.SE: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2424395/counting-the-number-of-same-elements-in-a-sequence)

Let $\mathcal{E'}$ be the set of all sequences where:

1. Any element of $\mathcal{E'}$ is a subset of $\mathbb{N}\cup \{0\}=\mathbb{N}_0$.
2. In any element of $\mathcal{E'}$, every distinct number appears finitely many times.

Let $\mathcal{E}$ be the set of all elements of $\mathcal{E'}$ which are in non-decreasing order with entries from $\mathbb{N}_0$. (We define a function $A:\mathcal{E'}\rightarrow \mathcal{E}$, where $A$ rearranges a element of $\mathcal{E'}$ in non-decreasing order.) $(*)$

Now choose an element (say, $S$) from $\mathcal{E}$. Define a function $\rho$ on $\mathcal{E}$ by $\rho(S)=(f(n))_{n=0}^{\infty}$, where $f:\mathbb{N}_0\rightarrow \mathbb{N}_0$, with $f(n)=$ the number of times $n$ appeared in the sequence $S$.

Let $\mathcal{H}\subset \mathcal{E}$ be the set of all such $S\in \mathcal{E}$ for which $\rho(S)\in \mathcal{E'}$. Arranging elements of $\rho(S)$ in non-decreasing order, we will get an element of $\mathcal{E}$, which is $A(\rho(S))$. Essentially, if $A(\rho(S))\in \mathcal{H}$, we can get $\rho(A(\rho(S)))\in \mathcal{E'}$. Again, arranging elements of $\rho(A(\rho(S)))$ in non-decreasing order, we will get an element of $\mathcal{E}$, which is $A(\rho(A(\rho(S))))=(A\circ\rho)^2(S)$. We continue this process, and will get a set of sequences $((A\circ\rho)^m(S))_{m=0}^{\infty}\subset \mathcal{H}$ with $(A\circ\rho)^0(S)=\rho^0(S)=S$.

---

**Questions:**

1. Consider the set, $((A\circ\rho)^m(S))_{m=0}^{\infty}$. Let $N\in \mathbb{N}$. Can we find a $N$, for a given $S\in \mathcal{E}$ such that $(A\circ\rho)^N(S)=S$?
2. Can we find a $S\in \mathcal{E}$, for each $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $(A\circ\rho)^N(S)=S$?

---

**What I want to know?**

$(*)$ Actually I want to know whether such $A$ really exists or not. If not, can anyone give an alternative way to formulate the problem, if possible? I wrote the whole problem, if someone is interested to know what it is.

Comment: You can make multiple fixed points for rho, and likely rearrange things to cause finite cycles.  One fixed point starts 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 4 5 5 5 6 6 6 6 7 7 ..., and there are at least countably many others.  You might try analyzing the larger space where infinitely many repetitions are allowed to help you find fixed points in the finite case.  Gerhard "Like Goodstein Sequences,  But Faster" Paseman, 2017.09.10.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman ,thanks, but I don't want to jump to $\rho$ until I know for sure that $A$ really exists or not. Otherwise there is no point of thinking about the problem at all.

Comment: You can consider an extension of A to sequences indexed by countable ordinals, and show that it works on the restricted set of your interest. You can also try a direct proof that A exists on your restricted set, but that will likely be more messy.  Gerhard "May Still Be A PA-Theorem" Paseman, 2017.09.10.

Comment: Just a very small comment: The set $\mathbb{N}\cup \{0\}$ is normally called $\mathbb{N}_0$ (for obvious reasons I guess).